# Need to analysis the physiological data

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, biology

I have to do a project to analysis the human physiological state. I have able to got the heart rate, ECG, and temperature sensor data. What things I have to analysis to get the human physiological states.

Is there any open data set available to analyse human state? like

if heart rate between 79 - 110 he is cool 
else if  heart rate between 111 - 120 he is stress

like this

Comment: It would be useful to have the heart rate, a psychological measure, and a note of any medications. Some medications such as caffeine raise the heart rate. Others, such as beta-blockers, depress the heart rate. People desensitize to some medications more than others.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at the NHanes data sets (http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes.htm).  They have many vital signs, so the heart rate would probably be there as well as ecg type measures in some of the data sets.  I don't know about the stress or similar variables, but search the documentation, it would not surprise me if a question along those lines were asked in at least one of the groups.